# Ember and Node.js Nginx Configuration amazon EC2 Ubuntu Server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, ember.js, nodes

I am getting this error when I try and load my site:

[image]

Reading into it, I think there is an issue with my frontend not being able to contact my backend. I've done a CURL to my backend inside the server and outside and everything works. Also deploying with Ember-Cli-mirage works fine as well, Leading me to believe there is an issue with my NGINX config files. I have two config files one for the front end and one for the backend:

Frontend Ember config:

```
 server {
 listen 80 default_server;
 listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
 root /usr/local/t;
 index index.html;
  location / {
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
 }
 }
```

My backend Node.js Express config:

```
 server {
   listen 80;
   server_name default_server;

    root /usr/local/cloudBackend;
   index index.html index.htm;

   access_log /var/log/nginx/cpe.access.log;
   error_log /var/log/nginx/cpe.error.log notice;

   #  auth_basic "Restricted";
   #  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: First, I suggest to look in `network` tab of chrome's development tools in order to see what request your front tries to make and what your back responses

Comment: You are getting a HTML content instead of JSON, which may be a 404 page or something else. See what is it and why?

Answer (score 0):

Added this to my Node.js headers and then it worked!

```
 res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```